# Callback Executes But Caller Doesn't

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-callback

I have the following jquery code placed inside the success response of an ajax call:

```
// Replace loading div with more posts button
loadingText.fadeOut(function(){
    moreButton.fadeIn();
});
```

Everything works fine on my local dev environment. However, the same code when executed on my qa server results in the `moreButton` fading in, but not `loadingText` fading out. Since `fadeIn()` is in the callback for `fadeOut()` I'm not sure how `fadeIn()` is executing but `fadeOut()` isn't. Both `moreButton` and `loadingText` are defined well before the ajax call.

Can someone explain what might be happening here and how I can fix it?

EDIT: Here's some more code.

```
// Show when more posts are loading
var loadingText = $(document.createElement('div'))
    .addClass('loading')
    .text('Loading...');
someDiv.append(loadingText);

// Click for more posts
var moreButton = $(document.createElement('button'))
    .addClass('more')
    .text('More Posts')
    .css({'display': 'none'});
someDiv.append(moreButton);

// Load posts when more posts button is clicked
moreButton.click(function(){
    loadArticles();
});

function loadArticles(){
    $.ajax({
        url: url,
        type: type,
        data:{data},
        success: function (html) {

           // Show preloaded posts
           $('.posts.hidden').removeClass('hidden');
           moreButton.fadeOut(function(){
               loadingText.fadeIn();
           });

           // Preload more posts in hidden div

           // Replace loading div with more posts button
           loadingText.fadeOut(function(){
                moreButton.fadeIn();
            });
        },
        error: function(html) {
            // Do something else
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Maybe `loadingText` doesn't contain the element you expect it to contain?

Comment: Works as it should: https://jsfiddle.net/eek8q2d0/1/ Something else is going on. Please post all relevant code: HTML, CSS and how you are assigning `loadingText` variable.

Comment: @VictorLevin I added some more code. I know that it *should* work because it works fine on my local dev site. The environment on my qa site must be executing the jquery differently, but I've never experienced this before so I don't know what's going on.

Comment: @Reggie. Still works: https://jsfiddle.net/eek8q2d0/2/ If it works on one server but not the other, please ensure that all JS libraries are loaded properly on your qa server. Also check browser console for any errors (hit F12) Also make sure that ajax call actually results in `success`. It's possible that your ajax call fails.

Comment: @VictorLevin All js is properly loaded and the console has no errors. If I step through the code in the Chrome debugger the code sometimes works as expected. This also points to it being some sort of timing issue...

Comment: @VictorLevin I don't think it's possible that my ajax call is failing. If my ajax call were failing, the success response wouldn't be initiated at all. `moreButton` would not be fading in if my ajax call were failing. Also, if I step through in Chrome's debugger it goes through the ajax success response.

Comment: What happens if you type it out like: `$(loadingText).fadeOut(600); $(moreButton).delay(600).fadeIn(600);` - should be the same, but just a check?

Comment: Almost certainly has to do with two animations called immediately overlapping.  I'd try to splice in a .stop(true,true) before each moreButton/loadingText reference within the success function and see if that helps.  Also, you don't need to create an anonymous function to call a named function: moreButton.click(loadArticles);

Comment: that is, moreButton.stop(true,true).fadeIn();  If that works, then most likely you'll need it on just the inner fadeIns, but at least it'll tell you if you're running into the problem of jQuery not quite being able to clean up the animation queue before starting another animation.

Comment: @Dtipson Thanks, I figured it out. Watching the tags for `loadingText` I noticed that sometimes it was actually fading in when it should have been fading out. I think you were right--the fade in and fade out functions were too close in time and something was going wrong. I solved it by using a callback so that the latter function didn't start until the former finished.